# How to use angular with require

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am attempting to display a list of items using angular loaded via require.

I have two files

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test App</title>
    <script data-main="/Scripts/app/main" src="../Scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCntrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in appCntrl.phones">
            {{phone.name}}
            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts/',
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    paths: {
                 'angular': 'lib/angular/angular.min',
                 'angular-resource': 'lib/angular/angular-resource.min'
    },
    shim: {
                 'angular': { 'exports': 'angular' },
                 'angular-resource': { deps: ['angular'] }
    }
});

require(['angular', 'angular-resource'], function (angular) {
    var mainMod = angular.module('mainMod', ['ngResource']);
    mainMod.controller('AppCntrl'['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.phones = [
          {
            'name': 'Nexus S',
            'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
          },
          {
            'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
          }
        ];
    }]);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['mainMod']);
});
```

I am not getting any console errors. Just an empty page

**UPDATE**

I made an update and now getting Error[ng:areq] I think this is progress

**UPDATE2**

I am not getting error

```
Cannot call method '$$minErr' of undefined
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
Error: [ng:areq]
```

Comment: Missing comma after 'AppCntrl'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are requiring angular-resource, it seems to be unneeded. Angular-route is required if you are using 1.2.0. And "appCntrl.phones" should just be "phones".

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3lWNEN8CeFzJxdSeso5r?p=preview)